# tree implemention with sum function in java

Tags: java, generics, abstract

I want to use abstract generic class to implement tree nodes which have a sum function to sum each node and all its children values. Please check if my following thoughts are OK.

```
public abstract class Tree<T extends Integer>{
  private Node<T extends Integer> node;
  public class Node<T>{
    private T data;
    private List<Node<T>> children;
  }
  public Tree<T>(T nodeData){
    node = new Node<T>();
    node.data = nodeData;
    node.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
  }

  public abstract <T extends Integer> T sum (Node<T> node);
}

public class IntegerTree<T extends Integer> extends Tree<T extends Integer>{
  public <T extends Integer> T sum (Node<T> node){
    if (node ==null)
       return 0;
    else
       return node.data+ sum(node.children);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your code work? Please go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. If it doesn't, please specify the exact issue.

Comment: You're going to have trouble with `T extends Integer`, because `Integer` is `final`.  You can't extend it.

Comment: Thank you David, is the code OK if I just change Integer to Number?

Comment: Well, you'll still have trouble with the expression `node.data + sum(node.children)`.  The `Number` class doesn't define what is meant by `+`.  I think you would have to do one of two things.  Either make an interface which has an `add` method, and specify that `T` must extend both your interface and the `Number` class; or write an abstract class that extends `Number` and provides an unimplemented `add` method.  Any class which can be used for `T` will have to supply its own implementation of `+`.